# WordPress Header Tag Unwanted Space

Tags: css, wordpress, header, space

I am trying to get rid of unwanted space in a WordPress page. Here is the link to the page: http://lectorbookclub.com/current-conversations/. I'm trying to use CSS to fix it because I only have access to editing the CSS and HTML.

I used Firebug to gather this code:

```
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <article id="post-12581" class="post-12581 post type-post status-publish format-                standard hentry category-fall-2013 category-uncategorized tag-end-of-year-post clear-fix">
    <div class="featured-image">
    <a href="http://lectorbookclub.com/2014/05/01/eng-202b-summary-post/" title="Permalink to Eng 202B Summary Post" rel="bookmark">
    <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/oxygen/images/archive-thumbnail-placeholder.gif?m=1335191815g" alt="" class="attachment-archive-thumbnail" scale="0"/>
    </a>
    </div>
    <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title">
    <div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="entry-date">
    <span class="byline">
    <span class="comments-link">
    <span class="edit-link">
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-summary clear-fix">
    <a href="http://lectorbookclub.com/2014/05/01/eng-202b-summary-post/"         title="Permalink to Eng 202B Summary Post" rel="bookmark" class="read-more">Read Article →</a>
```

Comment: You'll have to give us a little bit more info! What is the unwanted space?

Comment: When I hover over the space in Firebug, it points to <header class="entry-header">

Comment: Which space? Top, left, right, bottom? How do you want it to appear?

Comment: The awkward space is to the right of the entry-header. It's the space between the left [containing the date, name of author, Leave a comment] AND the black boxes containing excerpts of the content.

Comment: Could you restate your entire question?

Comment: How do I decrease the gap between the dates and their entries? On the left are the dates (followed by the authors and Leave a Comment link) and on the right are the entries (in boxes of a black background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options depending on how you want to go about this.

My first suggestion is simple just based off of what you have shared. (that said this does not mean this is the only way, or the best way or the clean way)

You may want to adjust your CSS to move the individual entries a few pixels from the right by adding a right margin.

```
.entry-summary {
    margin-right: 45px;
}
```

Or you may want to add a left margin to .entry-header

```
.entry-header {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

There are various other options as well. Hope this helps.

<sub>(try to be more concise and direct in the future. ask your question with all needed details for others to understand so that you may receive an answer more quickly and that others may feel more motivated to help!)</sub>

Comment: I tried changing the margins but it seems like the problem was outside of these tags. It seemed to be in the <article> tag which wraps around the entry-header and entry-summary.

Comment: I did a mix of editing the article tag and the margin-left for entry-header. Before, I was changing the entry-meta margins. Thanks captainrad!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS stylesheet:

```
#page {max-width: 960px; }
```

Substitute 960px for whatever size you want it to be.

Comment: It's for a class called entry-header in the <header> tag. Thanks though!

Comment: But where and how do you want that <div> box containing the date, author name etc to appear? Floated left? Inline? There's too many ways to do this and you aren't very specific.

Comment: Left as it is would be good. It's just that gap between the author name/date/comment and the entries in a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I realized it had to do with the article tag (which wraps around the date and the entries). I played around with the width of the article tag in CSS and this seemed to be the answer. Thank you all so much for looking at this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making the text in entry-header align right.

`header.entry-header { text-align: right; }`

I don't know how else `header.entry-header` is used in your theme, but on the page you provided, that would probably produce the alignment you are looking for.